# KeystoneJS date picker not selecting

Tags: keystonejs

The date picker in the admin UI doesn't seem to set date values on selection. It opens and I can select a date, but it doesn't actually set the value in the input.

version: 0.3.22

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be to give 4.0 beta shot.

`npm install --save keystone@next`

If the issue persists, raise an issue on [Github](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues).